# jquery ui theme not working with my template css

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Whenever I include my template css, jquery ui dialog box theme gets affected.

Here is my template css:

```
    *   {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
    html, body  {
        height: 100%;
        }
    body    {
        background: #fff;
        color: #393939;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 0px;
        line-height: 0;
        }
    #page-top-outer {
        background: url(../images/top_bg.jpg) top center repeat-x;
        /*border-bottom: 1px solid #7e7e7e;*/
        height: 92px;
        }
    #page-top   {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1260px;
        min-width: 850px;
        position: relative;
        }
    #logo   {
        float: left;
        margin: 45px 0 0 15px;
        }
    #logo   a   {
        display: block;
        }

    #content-outer  {
        background: url(../images/content_repeat.jpg) repeat-x;
        }
    #content    {
        color: #333;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 18px;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        max-width: 1260px;
        min-width: 780px;
        padding: 35px 0px 30px 0px;
        }


    /*************** Notifications ***************/
    .notification {
        position: relative;
        margin:15px  0 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-position: 10px 11px !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        font-size: 13px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }


    .attention {
        background: #fffbcc url('../images/icons/exclamation.png') 10px 11px no-repeat;
        border-color: #e6db55;
        color: #666452;
    }

    .information {
        background: #dbe3ff url('../images/icons/information.png');
        border-color: #a2b4ee;
        color: #585b66;
    }

    .success {
        background: #d5ffce url('../images/icons/tick_circle.png');
        border-color: #9adf8f;
        color: #556652;
    }

    .error {
        background: #ffcece url('../images/icons/cross_circle.png');
        border-color: #df8f8f;
        color: #665252;
    }

    .notification div {
        display:block;
        font-style:normal;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 36px;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }

    .notification .close {
        color:#990000;
        font-size:9px;
        position:absolute;
        right:5px;
        top:5px;
    }

    /************Table icons ***************/
    a.icon-plus {
        background: url(../images/icons/table_icon_plus.gif) no-repeat;
        display: block;
        height: 24px;
        margin: 0 8px 0 0;
        width: 24px;
        }
    a:hover.icon-plus   {
        background: url(../images/icons/table_icon_plus.gif) 0 -24px;
        }

    a.icon-edit {
        background: url(../images/icons/table_icon_edit.gif) no-repeat;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 24px;
        margin: 0 8px 0 0;
        width: 24px;
        }
    a:hover.icon-edit   {
        background: url(../images/icons/table_icon_edit.gif) 0 -24px;
        }
    a.icon-delete   {
        background: url(../images/icons/table_icon_delete.gif) no-repeat;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 24px;
        margin: 0 8px 0 0;
        width: 24px;
        }
    a:hover.icon-delete {
        background: url(../images/icons/table_icon_delete.gif) 0 -24px;
        }
    a.icon-tick {
        background: url(../images/icons/table_icon_tick.gif) no-repeat;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 24px;
        width: 24px;
        }
    a:hover.icon-tick   {
        background: url(../images/icons/table_icon_tick.gif) 0 -24px;
        }

    /******* Tooltip ******************/
    #tooltip    {
        background-color: #8c8c8c;
        border: 1px solid #767676;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: normal;
        opacity: 0.85;
        padding: 0 5px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 3000;
        }
    #tooltip h6, #tooltip div   {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        }

    /**********Table CSS************/

    /*  ACTIONS BOX ----------------------------------------------- */  
    #actions-box    {
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
        position: relative;
        }
    a.action-slider {
        background: url(../images/dropdown_actions.gif) no-repeat;
        display: block;
        height: 30px;
        width: 110px;
        }
    a.action-slider.activated   {
        background: url(../images/dropdown_actions.gif) no-repeat 0 -30px;
        display: block;
        height: 30px;
        width: 110px;
        }
    #actions-box-slider {
        background: url(../images/actions_slider_bg.gif) bottom no-repeat;
        display: none;
        left: 0;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 24px;
        width: 110px;
        }
    #actions-box-slider-inner   {
        font-size: 0px;
        line-height: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 108px;
        }
    a.action-delete {
        color: #272727;
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 20px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10px 0 5px 45px;
        width: 63px;
        }
    a.action-delete {
        background: #c7c7c7 url(../images/action_delete.gif) no-repeat 14px 5px;
        }
    a:hover.action-delete   {
        background: #949494 url(../images/action_delete.gif) no-repeat 14px 5px;
        color: #fff;
        }

    /********* Pagination **************/

    .pagination {
        float:right;
    }
    .page a,.current,.first a,.previous a,.next a,.last a{
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #717171;
        font: bold 11px Arial, sans-serif;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px white;
        padding: 5px 8px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
        background: #f9f9f9;

        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#e8e8e8',GradientType=0 );
    }

    .current{
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 0px 1px #3f789f;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        background: #aeadad;

        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aeadad 0%, #a4a6a7 100%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aeadad 0%, #a4a6a7 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #aeadad 0%, #a4a6a7 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #aeadad 0%, #a4a6a7 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(top, #8aeadad 0%, #a4a6a7 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#aeadad', endColorstr='#a4a6a7',GradientType=0 );
    }

    .page a:hover,.page a:hover,.current a:hover,.first a:hover,.previous a:hover,.next a:hover,.last a:hover{
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
        background: #fff;

        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fff', endColorstr='#e8e8e8',GradientType=0 );
    }

    .current a:hover {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        background: #99cefc;

        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #99cefc 0%, #57a1d8 100%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #99cefc 0%, #57a1d8 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #99cefc 0%, #57a1d8 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #99cefc 0%, #57a1d8 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(top, #99cefc 0%, #57a1d8 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#99cefc', endColorstr='#57a1d8',GradientType=0 );
    }

    /*******Custom form********/
    .form_errors ul {list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0; margin-left: 0;color: #d11111;}
    .form_errors ul li {
        background: url("../images/icons/error_circle.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent ;
        color: #f85507;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    form.custom label.form_label { display: block; margin-bottom:5px; font-size: 12px; }

    form.custom label.inline_label { display: inline;margin-right:12px; font-size: 12px }

    form.custom label.form_element_error {
        margin-left: 4px;
        background: url("../images/icons/error_circle.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent ;
        color: #f85507;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    form.custom input.text-input,form.custom textarea {
        padding: 6px;
        font-size: 13px;
        background: #fff url('../images/bg-form-field.gif') top left repeat-x;
        border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
        color: #333;
        border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
    }

    form.custom input[type="checkbox"],form.custom input[type="radio"] {
        padding: 0;
        background: none;
        border: 0;
    }

    form.custom input.text-input:focus, form.custom textarea:focus {
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(204,204,204, 1);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(204,204,204, 1);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(204,204,204, 1);
        border:1px solid rgba(204,204,204, 0.8);
    }
    form.custom input[type="submit"] {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
        box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
        background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f9f9f9), color-stop(1, #e9e9e9) );
        background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100% );
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#e9e9e9');
        background-color:#f9f9f9;
        -moz-border-radius:6px;
        -webkit-border-radius:6px;
        border-radius:6px;
        border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
        display:inline-block;
        color:#666666;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:6px 24px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    form.custom input[type="submit"]:hover {
        background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e9e9e9), color-stop(1, #f9f9f9) );
        background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100% );
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e9e9e9', endColorstr='#f9f9f9');
        background-color:#e9e9e9;
    }
    form.custom input[type="submit"]:active {
        position:relative;
        top:1px;
    }

    /*********Step wise css*********/
    #step-holder {
    font-family: Tahoma;
        height:39px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }   

    .step-no {
        float:left;
        height:29px;
        width:18px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 18px;
        padding:10px 0 0 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .step-no-off {
        float:left;
        height:29px;
        width:18px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 18px;
        padding:10px 0 0 0;
        text-align: center;
        color:#cbcbcb;
    }

    .step-dark-left {
        float:left;
        background: url(../images/step_dark_left.gif) no-repeat;
        height:27px;
        padding:13px 15px 0 25px;
        font-size: 13px;
        color:#fff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .step-dark-left a{

        font-size: 13px;
        color:#fff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .step-dark-right {
        float:left;
        width:12px;
        background: url(../images/step_dark_right.gif) no-repeat;
        height:39px;
    }
    .step-dark-round {
        float:left;
        width:8px;
        height:39px;
        background: url(../images/step_dark_round.gif) no-repeat;
    }

    .step-light-left {
        float:left;
        height:27px;
        padding:13px 15px 0 25px;
        font-size: 13px;
        background: url(../images/step_light_left.gif) no-repeat;
        height:39px;
        color:#cbcbcb;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .step-light-left a{
        font-size: 13px;
        color:#cbcbcb;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .step-light-right {
        float:left;
        width:12px;
        background: url(../images/step_light_right.gif) no-repeat;
        height:39px;
    }
    .step-light-round {
        float:left;
        width:8px;
        height:39px;
        background: url(../images/step_light_round.gif) no-repeat;
    }

    /* FOOTER -------------------------------------------------------------- */
    #footer {
    height: 70px;

        margin: 80px auto 0px auto;
        padding: 0px 0 0 0;
        text-align: left;
        min-width: 780px;
        max-width: 1260px;
        }
    #footer-left    {
        color: #818181;
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 11px;
        padding: 15px 0 15px 25px;
        margin: 0 20px;
        border-top: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
        } 
    #footer-left a  {
        color: #818181;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
    #footer-left     a.selected,
    #footer-left     a:hover    {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        }

    /*******Content box **********/
    .content-box {
                    border: 1px solid #ccc;
                    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
                    background: #fff;
                    }
    .filter-box.closed-box {
        width:90px;
        float:right;
    }

    .content-box-header {
                    background: #e5e5e5 url('../images/bg-content-box.gif') top left repeat-x;
                    margin-top: 1px;
                    height: 40px;
    }

    .content-box-header h3 {
                    padding: 12px 15px 10px;
                    float: left;
                    }
    .content-box-tabs{
    width:450px;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    padding:12px 15px 0 0;
    margin-top:-4px;
    text-align:right;
    }
    .content-box-tabs span{
    cursor:pointer;

    }
    .content-box-tabs a{
    cursor:pointer;

    }
    ul.content-box-tabs {
                    float: right;
                    padding: 12px 15px 0 0 !important;
                    margin: 0 !important;

                    }

    ul.content-box-tabs li {
                    float: left;
                    margin: 0;

                    background-image: none !important;
                    padding: 8px 10px !important;
                    cursor:pointer;
                    }

    ul.content-box-tabs li a {
                    color: #333;

                    display: block;
                    margin: 1px;
                    border-bottom: 0;
                    }

    ul.content-box-tabs li:hover,a:hover {
                    color: #57a000;
                    }              

    ul.content-box-tabs li a.current {
                    background: #fff;
                    border: 1px solid #ccc;
                    border-bottom: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    }

    .content-box-content {
                    /*padding: 20px 0;*/
                    font-size: 13px;
                    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
                    overflow:auto;

                    }

    .content-box,.content-box-header,ul.content-box-tabs li a.current,.shortcut-button,.notification {
                    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
                    border-radius: 6px;
                    }

    .content-box-header {
                    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
                    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
                    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
                    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
                    }

    .closed-box .content-box-header {
                    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
                    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
                    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
                    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
                    }

    ul.content-box-tabs li a.current {
                    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
                    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
                    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
                    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
                    }

    /************ Table ************/

    #content table {
                    width: 100%;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    }

    #content table thead th {
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 15px;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
                    }

    #content tbody {
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
                    }

    #content tbody tr {
                    background: #fff;
                    }

    #content tbody tr.alt-row {
                    background: #f3f3f3;
                    }

    #content table td,
    #content table th {
                    padding: 10px;
                    line-height: 1.3em;
                    text-align:left;
                    }        

    #content table tfoot td .bulk-actions {
                    padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
                    } 


    /* GENERAL --------------------------------------------------------*/ 
    .fr {
        float: right;
        }
    a   {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
    a:hover {
        }
    .clear  {
        clear: both;
        font-size: 0px;
        height: 0;
        line-height: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        }
    img {
        border: 0;
        }
    p   {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        }
    form    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
    .line   {
        border-top: 1px solid #dcdada;
        font-size: 0px;
        height: 1px;
        line-height: 0px;
        margin: 20px 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
    .font11 {
        font-size: 11px;
        }
```

Here is jsfiddle link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h89Az/)

I am not much of a designer. I think Some css rule is overriding jquery ui css rule. Can somebody figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
body    {
  background: #fff;
  color: #393939;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

to:

```
body    {
  background: #fff;
  color: #393939;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you CSS hierarchy. CSS class will override another class in those cases:

1. The CSS is loaded after the former, for example:

   a { color: blue; }
   a { color: red; }
   In this case the color will be red
2. The CSS selector is more "specific", for example:

   div a { color: blue }
   a { color: red }
   In this case the color of an anchor tag inside a div will be blue, although the red color class is loaded after.

There is another case that you use the "important" keyword (`color: black !important`) - this will override anyway, but I guess you don't use it.